# Split-path powershell

Tags: powershell

This must be very simple but yea I want to split-path "E:\Somefolder\ps\pow.ps1"

So by using

```
 Split-path "Path" -Parent
```

I get the parent path i.e."E:\Somefolder\ps" but I only want "E:\Somefolder" 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well! well! 
I was able to do it using following line:

```
 Split-Path (Split-path $MyInvocation.InvocationName -Parent)
```